# форматирование текста в string.xml

Tags: android, xml

У меня есть текст в файле *string.xml*  (текст очень большой).
Он загружен в `TextView`. При загрузке приложения, когда открывается `Layout` данной `TextView`  текст без абзацев, пунктов и т.д.

---

Вопрос:

Как можно отформатировать текст внутри файла  *string.xml*, чтобы он красиво отображался в `Layout`  с абзацами и пунктами?

Comment: Использовать теги

Comment: А если использовать массив? (<string-array>)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для переноса строки используйте управляющий символ `\n` в строковом ресурсе.

Так же можно использовать некоторые теги:

```
<b>жирный шрифт</b> 
<i>наклонный шрифт</i>  
<u>подчеркнутый шрифт</u>
```

Пример:

```
<string name="text"><b>Заголовок</b> \n\n Этот текст <i>наклонный</i></string>
```

На этом возможности форматирования внутри строкового ресурса с привязкой  к виджету через разметку заканчиваются. Однако при некотором шаманстве можно использовать полное HTML-форматирование:

```
<string name="color_text"><![CDATA[<font color="#ff0000">My Color Text</font>]]></string>
```

То есть HTML-текст помещается между `<![CDATA[  ]]>`

В коде нужно указать, что ресурс содержит HTML-форматирование:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.color_text)));
```

Comment: т.е если у меня  больш. количества текста,я все руками проставляю?