# Стилизация текста в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные средства для стилизации текста в TextView. Т.е. что бы было более понятно приведу пример. Например у меня есть fb2 книга. В ней есть ссответсвующие теги указывающиие, где жирный текст, где курсив и т.д. Есть ли средство в андроиде, которое само все это обработает и выведет как надо?

Comment: Описанные вами тэги по умолчанию поддерживаются. Но далеко не все

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458549/177345

Comment: Ничего не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартным средством добавления таких фич является `SpannableString`, проще понять из примера как это работает:

```
   Spannable text = new SpannableString("This is underline and bold text.");
        text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 8, 17, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 22, 26, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
   textView.setText(text);
```

В этом примере часть текста становится с подчерком, а часть жирным.

`SpannableString` может быть самым разным - можно варьировать размер, цвет, шрифт и проч. Список [спанов здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html)