# Как вставить таблицу в текст из ресурса strings.xml Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Имеется текст в ресурсе strings.xml. Как в тот текст добавить небольшую текстовую таблицу? Студия предлагает только ,,. Но с таким набором таблицу не собрать(((

Comment: вопрос не ясен. вам нужно из символов составить рамки  таблицы или что?

Comment: Возможно человек хочет полноценный HTML код в ресурсы запихнуть...

Comment: Вообще-то хотел, если честно))

Comment: Я так понял, что кроме вариантов с символами никаких больше нет?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458549/177345

Comment: только вот почему то с table такой прием не канает. Весь текст с ячеек таблици отображается в одну строку((