# Жирный текст в TextView через чистый XML

Tags: android, xml, стилизация

Имеется нативный TextView, в нём необходимо выделить жирным некоторые слова. Сам текст задаётся через свойство XML, то есть **Java в этой задаче не нужна**, потому что с помощью Java решение не раз разбиралось, к примеру здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold/14371107

Нас же интересует аналогичное решение, но через прямое задание текста:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Приложение создано совместным трудом. Наибольший вклад внесли:"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Допустим, мы хотим выделить текст "Наибольший вклад внесли:". Что нужно дописать в строку в таком случае?

Мой вариант, который бы работал, если бы было включено HTML преобразование:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Приложение создано совместным трудом. <b>Наибольший вклад внесли:</b>"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

То есть, ожидается следующее оформление текста:

> Приложение создано совместным трудом. **Наибольший вклад внесли:**

Результат, которого удалось достичь:

> Приложение создано совместным трудом. Наибольший вклад внесли:

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458549/177345

Comment: @pavlofff что это?

Comment: Вам вариант подтягивать текст с нужним Вам форматированием в TextView из ресурсов не подходит? Только прописывать текст непосредственно в виджете?

Comment: @V.March подтягивать то можно, суть совсем не в этом. Java использовать нельзя. Чёрным по белому написал

Comment: Так Вы и можете подтянуть без джавы.

Comment: В ресурсах свое форматирование сделать и ссылку на этот ресурс закинуть в место текста в xml разметку.

Comment: @V.March если у Вас есть такое решение, то смело можете его писать в "Ответы". Если, конечно, удовлетворяет условиям вопроса

Comment: *что это?* - это решение проблемы в вашем вопросе. Нужно нажать на ссылку и прочитать его.

Comment: @pavlofff это - решение проблемы. Но не моей. Чёрным по белому написано: "без Java". А что по ссылке? Java! P.S. Удалите свой бесполезный, некачественный комментарий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант.

Так в виджете:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/formated_text" //это ссылка на ресурс с Вашим форматированием
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Так в ресурсах:

```
<resources>

    <string name="formated_text">Приложение создано совместным трудом. <b>Наибольший вклад внесли:</b></string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Действительно работает! Но в окне предпросмотра показывается без стилизации.

Comment: Рад что Вам подошел вариант. А по поводу окна предпросмотра, то это очень неуютно не только для этого виджета. В студии есть еще много виджетов, которые не отображаются корректно до того пока не запустишь на виртуальном девайсе или на реальном устройстве. С этим еще столкнетесь. Особенно со списками.

Comment: Круто, даже не знал, что там можно :)