# Как форматировать текст в андроид студио через xml?

Tags: android

Как отформатировать , чтобы текст был аккуратный, не в кучу? Надо разделить на абзацы, пыталась это сделать таким образом

```
 <string name="contacts">
    <p>Место нахождения организации:
        <br />- юридический адрес - ул. К. Воробьёвых, д.20, Чебоксары<br />
        - фактический адрес - ул. Эльгера, 10А, Чебоксары<br />
        - фактический адрес нахождения администрации - Московский проспект, 14Б, Чебоксары<br />
        Телефон: (8352) 38-79-30<br />Email: kulibin.club@gmail.com<br />
        Администрация: пн-пт: 9.00-18.00</p>
    </string>
```

Первое время работало, но добавила скролл и все полетело))
Выглядит вот так и еще за рамки текст выходит, как исправить?

После того, как поставила в резметке везде match_parent, стало так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите разметку. Похоже, что у вас ширина для TextView выставлена в `wrap_content`, тогда как надо - `match_parent`

Comment: да, я сама до этого догнала, сейчас веде match_parent поставила, немнго изменилось в лучшую сторону, но текст все равно без абзацев

Comment: А как вы текст добавляете? Если у вас там HTML - то он ограниченно поддерживается и то надо оборачивать его во что-то типа `Html.fromHtml("HTML TEXT HERE")`.

Comment: как текст добавляю написала выше, через string и разметку html. А вот про то, что надо оборачивать, поподробнее, это вот как-то так?     TextView description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        description.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.description)));

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458549/177345

Answer (score 0):

Перенос текста в пределах одной фразы осуществляется через \n.
Например

```
 description.setText("Адрес:" + "\n" + "Чебоксары");
```

Этот же приём можно использовать в xml